# Error or fail not being reached when Ajax fails to fetch JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on below Ajax code in JavaScript, I am trying to pop up a dialog box when the URL could not load the JSON properly the reason may be either expired token or incorrect token, in any case, I am expecting the code to hit the error or fail but it's not happening. When the URL could load the JSON successfully, success and complete blocks are being hit as expected but nothing is being hit when URL fails. I have tried to use `async: false` and tried to check with a boolean variable weHaveSuccess but `console.log(weHaveSuccess);` which is in the last line of the code is getting executing even before success/error is being executed and it seems to me like its still loading asynchronously. I would like to know why error block is not being hit when the JSON load from URL is getting failed.

My code

```
function checkUser(myURL, newAccessToken, weHaveSuccess) {

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",

        dataType: "jsonp",

        async: false,

        url: myURL + newAccessToken,

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        },

        success: function (data) {

            console.log("Hello 2 " + JSON.stringify(data));

            weHaveSuccess = true;

            console.log('Message from Success ' + weHaveSuccess);

        },

        complete: function () {
            console.log('Message from Complete ' + weHaveSuccess);
        }

    }).done(function (data) {
        alert("Success");
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("Failed");
    }).always(function () {
        alert("In Always");
    });

    console.log(weHaveSuccess);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you handling "error" and "success" but also handling "done" and fail"? You only need to implement it one way, not both.

Comment: Tried this and it hits all the right handlers: https://jsfiddle.net/1rLqcLkb/ I get the two alerts "Failed" and "In Always", and in the console I get the "Status" and "Error" lines, followed by the data object from `fail`.

Comment: Initially, I was just using Success/Error and since it didn't work I was playing around with done/fail.

Comment: Can you show how the server script reports an error? The error/done code is only run if it returns an HTTP error code or the JSON can't be decoded. If the server reports the error in the JSON data, that will be treated as success.

Comment: Be careful using `XMLHttpRequest` as the name of an argument, as that is the exact name of a global class. Better to call it something like `xhr`.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests are asynchronous. It takes time for a remote request to be made and responded to. You will have to write your post-response code within the `success` function or call another function from there, not within the same scope as where the call is initiated.

I am taking a bit of a guess here about what your server returns on failure. An AJAX request success means simply that a `200 OK` response was received, without any consideration of the contents of the data. If an error is simply a change in the data you will need do one of the following to show an error:

1. Have the server set a [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) header on failure, perhaps `400 Bad Request`.
2. In the `success` function look within your `data` for whatever error response you are expecting and trigger the `alert()` there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `console.log(weHaveSuccess);` fires first, because the `$.ajax()` is asynchronous while console.log is not so ajax will be triggered and return the promise when finishes, but the browser will continue with the script.
In the jQuery ajax docs says:

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation.

It's hard to debug without seeing the response, maybe you can add some info from the network or a URL?

Comment: Sure.... for example, if `url: "https://api.id.me/api/public/v2/attributes.json?access_token=" + 10576c9012b248f782529d408ef49d54`  then neither success nor error is being reached. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about if you try the following:
Add the `jsonp` setting to your `$.ajax()` function for the callback that will handle the response and console.log there:

```
function myCallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: myCallback,
...
```

Comment: Tried it, with `url: "https://api.id.me/api/public/v2/attributes.json?access_toke‌​n=" + 10576c9012b248f782529d408ef49d54` but callback function is not getting called. Thanks for the reply.